# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Item to Item

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, iterator, type-mismatch

```
public class RandomizedQueue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private Item[] s;
    private int N;

    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        return new RQIterator<Item>();
    }

    private class RQIterator<Item> implements Iterator<Item> {

        private Item[] copy;
        private int newItems;

        public RQIterator() {
            copy = (Item[]) new Object[N];
            for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s[i] != null)
                    copy[k++] = s[i];
            }
            newItems = N;
        }

        //hasNext(), next(), remove() methods..
    }
}
```

On the line `copy[k++] = s[i]`, I am getting the Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Item to Item, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Can somebody tell? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your inner class `RQIterator` is declaring a new type parameter `Item` that is distinct from the type parameter `Item` that its enclosing class `RandomizedQueue` is declaring.

However, the `Item` type parameter from `RandomizedQueue` is still in scope, because `RQIterator`, as a nested class, isn't a `static` nested class.  Just use `Item` from `RandomizedQueue`.

```
private class RQIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
```

Also the creation of the iterator in `iterator()` won't need the type parameter either.

```
public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    return new RQIterator();
}
```

Comment: Ohk, makes sense. Why should a static nested class behave any differently?

Comment: The type parameters declared on classes are only in scope for non-static members of a class.  Note that it's possible to declare `Item` as a generic type parameter on a `static` nested class, but then you wouldn't have access to the non-`static` instance variables in `RandomizedQueue`.